# Do summoned creatures give extra experience points, or are they part of the summoner's XP?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, experience-points, summoning

Let's say we fight a [dretch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/dretch) worth 600 XP. That dretch summons 2 more dretches, each usually also worth 600 XP. If we defeat all three dretches, would we get 600 XP or 1800 XP?

Comment: I'm interested to know how the goblin summons more goblins.  I'm assuming you mean the "casting a spell to conjure them from another plane" type of summoning, but in this particular case I wonder if you don't mean the "calling for help" type of summoning - in which case, they're worth full XP....  I think I'll write an answer.

Comment: ruedi, I see you've accepted gatherer818's answer that also covers goblins calling for help. Could you please answer the question above this one directly though? Are you talking about using spells or magic to “teleport” goblins into the fight, or are you asking about goblins who just call for help? This is important because if you mean the second, the question needs editing to say that clearly for the benefit of future readers and answerers.

Comment: the situation en detail was yesterday that we played WotR (thrird session) and one of the encounters (I was not sure but I think it was a dreadge. I just used goblins in my example) summoned, during the fight, two more of its kind and we killed them all. Our GM was not sure how many XP we get, each creature was worth 400 XP. Does this claryfies my question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically, every creature fought gives experience.  However, certain effects (especially summoning) can be exceptions.  In general, **experience is not awarded because a creature used its abilities.**

If Goblin A called for help and two more goblins came, those goblins award full exp.  If Goblin A used an alchemical item to attract a pair of wolves in the area to attack the party, the wolves award full exp.  If Goblin A's mounted on a goblin dog, the goblin dog gives full exp (usually...).

If Goblin A used a special quality to make two duplicates of himself, those duplicates do not award exp.  If Goblin A cast *summon nature's ally* to summon a wolf, that wolf would not award exp.  If Goblin A fights alongside (or astride) his goblin dog Animal Companion, Mount, or Familiar, the goblin dog would not award exp.

Note that in the cases where the creatures don't award exp, the goblin himself probably gives more exp than in the previous examples.  He's got a weird template applied, or levels in a class with spellcasting or an animal companion rather than being a "Small humanoid (goblin) warrior 1" or whatever the Bestiary lists a for a generic gobbo.

TL;DR:  If Creature B only exists because of Creature A's ability, Creature B is already included in Creature A's experience award.

Answer (score 6):

### No

The GMG has a bit near the XP table that explains summoned creatures don't count as they are already included in the CR. There's an example that if the caster had used a fireball instead of summoning it wouldn't change CR.